# Muscle-Mass Workout Routine for 14-Year-Old

Tags: muscle-mass

so I'm a 14-year-old who wants to maintain a low body fat, and also have a muscular physique in about a year.

I am 5' 11" (about 180 cm) and weigh around 126 pounds (about 54 KG).  I think I maintain a low body fat since my ribs are very barely noticeable.  I have ab muscles from working out in the past (as a 12-year-old) and have put my focus on my triceps and core so far.

I have a pull-up bar, a bench, and 15-pound (about 7 KG) dumbbells.

My questions are:

What weight dumbbells should I be lifting?
What exercises should I do?
How long will it take for me to grow a visible muscular physique?
What should my diet be?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, do not worry yourself with lifting weights just yet.

Teenagers have a lot of natural growth yet to do, and that's going to happen with or without weightlifting.

If you wish to get a lean and muscular body, your best bet is to enlist in some sports club. Not only will that type of training help you achieve your goal, but you will have a coach who can make a strength program specifically for *you* in particular.

Unfortunately, simply knowing your age and weight isn't enough for us to create a safe program for you, because we don't know if you have any conditions. And you might not even know about them yet either.

You will find that in certain sports, the athletes are very well built.

Some suggestions;

- American football
- rugby
- gymnastics
- track and field
- soccer
- tennis

You'll find that most athletes in these sports have very lean and muscular bodies, as is required to perform optimally.

Answer (score 0):

You display far too much concerned with details. Don't get hung up on any aspect, and whatever you do don't sweat the small stuff. Let your body dictate how much you do and how much you lift. Go for perfecting technique rather than attempting very heavy weights. Research established sites you can trust. Look at what you eat, and remember no fads, no silver bullets. Just good balanced diet, with plenty of variety. Forget supplement, pills, and energy drinks. Water is fine and inexpensive.
Remember there are very many great routines using just body weight. Don't neglect the aerobic element, and keep off the scale. You will get fit, strong, and build the muscle you need in good time using a variety of exercises. Hope this is not too much information to digest in one go. David W Cornwall

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience let me recommend you: continue to do bodyweight-exercise for 2-3 more years then switch to weight-lifting but without completely leaving bodyweight behing, do of every variation possible, chin-ups, pull-ups etc; push-ups, diamond push-ups, elevated push-ups, etc; dips, one-handed dips, dips with elevated-legs, etc; crunches, biking, running, etc; add weight to the different exercises, and after you feel you're not progressing as you used to then start weight-lifting. You'll get big while keeping vascularity, seriously, this is the best approach you could ever have, look at the story of many professional bodybuilders and you'll see they where already vascular when they started, most people who start lifting weights and were never athletic fail to acquire that aesthetic look, and they look so lame even after continuous years of training and all kinds of dieting.